# Error when I try update password with Firebase Auth in android studio, Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I try to update password the app crashes.
I would appreciate it if you could help me quickly.

LOG:

> win=Window{c86f864 u0 com.example.finalprojectorisamarel/com.example.finalprojectorisamarel.ChangePasswordActivity} destroySurfaces: appStopped=true cleanupOnResume=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false win.mViewVisibility=8 caller=com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:6539 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:6520 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.notifyAppStopped:6584 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.activityStopped:7172 com.android.server.wm.ActivityClientController.activityStopped:258 android.app.IActivityClientController$Stub.onTransact:613 com.android.server.wm.ActivityClientController.onTransact:136

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

user.updatePassword(etAgain.getText().toString())
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(ChangePasswordActivity.this, "Password update", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ChangePasswordActivity.this, "Error, password not updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I cannot see any exception there. Can you please provide the entire error message that crashed the app along with the line of code that produces it? Besides that, what exactly is `etAgain`?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently changing the password using Firebase Auth is a bit complicated. So when you login to your account early, you have the option to change the password, but after some time, you have to reauthenticate yourself and then update the password. And you should also have the old password

```
user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String email = user.getEmail();
AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(email, oldpassword);

user.reauthenticate(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                user.updatePassword(etAgain.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                                            // Task failed
                                        }else {
                                            // Password Changed
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                        }else {
                            // Auth Failed
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Check out the official firebase documentation for further doubts.